# jQuery UI Draggable and Page Scrolling (on mobile)

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-ui, mobile, scroll

I have a page full of draggable items (only in horizontal).

If I open my page on a touch device I can't scroll the page down, obviously because the page is full of draggable elements. How can I make the page scrollable again?

Here's the draggable() code I'm using:

```
$('li').draggable({
axis: 'x',
drag: function( event, ui ) {
    if(ui.position.left > 0)
        ui.position.left = 0;
    if(ui.position.left < -250)
        ui.position.left = -250;
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone needs this:

The problem can be solved by using the "handle" option of draggable().
For example, if I have a div with a width of 500px, I can insert another (transparent) div inside it aligned to the right (for example) and with a width of 250px. Then I set this last div as the handle of the draggable div.

Answer (score 2):

Using a handle is the obvious choice, but in some instances it's not a option.

In my scenario I had an inbox list whose items that you could drag to the left or right to expose action buttons. The entire inbox item must be draggable -- employing a drag handle would be unintuitive.

jQuery's `draggable` prevents vertical scrolling on touch screens if the touch was initiated inside a `draggable` element. So if the screen was filled with draggable inbox items, then the user would become trapped -- unable to scroll up or down.

The solution that worked for me was to measure any change in the cursor's vertical position and use `window.scrollBy` to manually scroll the window by the same amount:

```
var firstY = null;      
var lastY = null;
var currentY = null;
var vertScroll = false;
var initAdjustment = 0;

// record the initial position of the cursor on start of the touch
jqDraggableItem.on("touchstart", function(event) {
    lastY = currentY = firstY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
});

// fires whenever the cursor moves
jqDraggableItem.on("touchmove", function(event) {
    currentY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
    var adjustment = lastY-currentY;

    // Mimic native vertical scrolling where scrolling only starts after the
    // cursor has moved up or down from its original position by ~30 pixels.
    if (vertScroll == false && Math.abs(currentY-firstY) > 30) {
        vertScroll = true;
        initAdjustment = currentY-firstY;
    }

    // only apply the adjustment if the user has met the threshold for vertical scrolling
    if (vertScroll == true) {
        window.scrollBy(0,adjustment + initAdjustment);
        lastY = currentY + adjustment;
    }

});

// when the user lifts their finger, they will again need to meet the 
// threshold before vertical scrolling starts.
jqDraggableItem.on("touchend", function(event) {
    vertScroll = false;
});
```

This will closely mimic native scrolling on a touch device.