# jquery draggable x axis disable page scroll on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, draggable

I am making a slider that have 3 images and they are draggable with limits , I am using UI touch punch to make the mobile drag work.

This is my js code so far :

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
axis: "x",
drag: function(event, ui) {

    //$(window).scrollTo(0, scrollPage);
    //window.scrollBy(0,scrollPage);
    if (ui.position.left > 0) {
        newLeft = 0;
    } else if (ui.position.left < max_drag) {
        newLeft = max_drag;
    } else {
        newLeft = ui.position.left;
    }
    ui.position.left = newLeft;
}
});
```

and this is what i want to achieve :
[image]
now everything works except on mobile when i scroll vertically over the draggable element it doesn't scroll even tho the draggable is only on x axis.

I have searched and fuond this : 
[jQuery UI draggable prevents scrolling on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377138/jquery-ui-draggable-prevents-scrolling-on-mobile)
And 
[jQuery UI Draggable and Page Scrolling (on mobile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461428/jquery-ui-draggable-and-page-scrolling-on-mobile) 
but I couldnt get a clear solution or answer.